# Unit testing ios property

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

Today I had a small problem to solve.

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) NSmutableArray *itemsToDelete;
```

Actually the problem was when the delete method gets called, the for loop determines that the itemsToDelete is empty. When changed to strong everything started working. Now I want to unit test my change. How can I write unit test and make sure everything is working?

Comment: You want to unit-test if a strong property works better than a weak one (on an otherwise non retained instance variable)?

Comment: I actually want to test if the strong actually fixed the issue.

Comment: Unit tests are used for checking interaction between objects and object elements. If you know that strong is fixing you problem you do not need unit test to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually test the change by using

```
    @autorelease
   {
      initialize your property;
   }
```